# rsync: Copy speed decreases while syncing two directories

Tags: rsync, performance

I am using `rsync` on `fedora 20` to sync my directories. I am using the command below:-

```
$ rsync --progress -a srcDir DestDir
```

But, as rsync copies files, copy speed decreases significantly. Here is my output:-

```
sending incremental file list
./
ABCD.01.Episode.06.Xvid.avi
    112,523,264 100%   23.32MB/s    0:00:04 (xfr#1, to-chk=69/76)
ABCD.01.Episode.07.Xvid.avi
    159,942,656 100%   31.08MB/s    0:00:04 (xfr#2, to-chk=68/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.08.Xvid.avi
    135,442,432 100%   25.37MB/s    0:00:05 (xfr#3, to-chk=67/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.09.Xvid.avi
    155,904,000 100%    2.09MB/s    0:01:11 (xfr#4, to-chk=66/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.10.Xvid.avi
    206,614,528 100%    1.01MB/s    0:03:15 (xfr#5, to-chk=65/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.11.Xvid.avi
    167,616,512 100%    1.00MB/s    0:02:39 (xfr#6, to-chk=64/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.12.Xvid.avi
    144,068,608 100%    1.00MB/s    0:02:16 (xfr#7, to-chk=63/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.13.Xvid.avi
    176,902,144 100% 1021.79kB/s    0:02:49 (xfr#8, to-chk=62/76)
ABCD.02.Episode.14.Xvid.avi
    171,210,752 100%    1.00MB/s    0:02:42 (xfr#9, to-chk=61/76)
ABCD.03.Episode.15.Xvid.avi
    176,295,936 100%  999.01kB/s    0:02:52 (xfr#10, to-chk=60/76)
```

Can anybody please tell me what might be causing it? Or, how can I get a constant speed while using rsync or any other tool?

Comment: Where are the two directories mounted? What filesystems are on both?

Comment: ext4 to ntfs. Internal Hard drive to External Backup drive (WD My Passport Ultra).

Comment: This answer may help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89318/copying-to-an-external-ntfs-partition-slows-down-when-i-copy-many-files-at-once

Comment: You mean to say that I should write a `for loop` in a shell file and copy each file one by one. Or, If I use * in place of file name in cp command, bash will execute cp command for each file. That way, there won't be multiple files getting copied in parallel. Still, it seems like `rsync` itself is copying files sequentially, isn't it?

Comment: If you can, why not (as an experiment) reformat (or shrink a partition to make space for another) the external drive as `ext4` and run your test again. Also, try using `cp` instead of `rsync`.  You may be able to narrow down where the bottleneck is.  1Mb/s over USB is pretty poor.

Comment: 1MB/sec is really slow for a USB hard drive - that's USB 1.1 speed. Maybe check the cable, or if you're running in Virtualbox, check that USB 2.0 is enabled.

Comment: Was running it through live USB.

Comment: OK. Anthon's answer explains why the transfer rate slows down after the buffers in RAM fill up. If you'd like, post on superuser.com for help from users there about why your system hardware can only do 1MB/sec.

Answer (score 4):

The speed doesn't decrease. It slowly approaches the real speed that was there from the start.

Such copies normally involve buffers at the OS level and these need to be pushed out for real, what the application doesn't notice. Before they fill up, they are measuring how fast things get copied in the output buffer, and once that is filled your network speed starts to show up (varying a bit, often depending on what else you are doing).